# what is the use of prototype property in javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

What is the use of prototype property when properties can be added to object even without it?

```
var o = {};

o.x = 5;
o.y = test;

test = new function(){ alert("hello"); };
```

Comment: Your last line does not make much sense. It has nothing to do with prototype, and you don't use `new function() { }`.

Comment: @pimvdb - you actually can - it's an anonymous, immediately invoked constructor function.

Comment: -1 because this question is asked soooo much

Comment: @hvgotcodes i am not asking what is prototypal inheritance. I just saw that i can add properties to a object like this also. So the question was how it is different from doing it with prototype than.

Comment: @Moreover the link you have posted is having different view from what i want to understand.

Comment: Please understand the question before closing it. I am not asking the definitions.

Comment: SO is changing .. there are less people answering more people closing and suggesting to check some other question as a possible duplicate. It looks like its converting more into a search engine again. Loosing its beauty of newbies to ask learn and grow. If it has to be just search google is better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding a method / property to a prototype is adding it to all objects with that prototype in their prototype chain.

Your code is adding a method/property to a single instance.

To make use of prototypes you need to create your objects using new.  If you create an object via an object literal you aren't specifying the prototype for the object, as far as I know you can't set the prototype retrospectively.

Answer (score 3):

You can use it to create new methods for an existing object.

```
String.prototype.displayFirstCharacter = function(){
   alert(this.substr(0,1));
}

"my string, first char should be 'm'".displayFirstCharacter();
```